# Tabbing breaks SO's ask question form in IE8

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When creating an answer, accidental Tab can ruin the session](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87844/when-creating-an-answer-accidental-tab-can-ruin-the-session)

When I try to ask a question on SO with IE8, press `Tab`, go back to the edit box, do it again, etc., two things happen:

1. The text of the **Post Your Answer** button changes (dots appear)
2. The page freezes and I can't edit my post; I can only close the tab

I don't know whether this is an issue with my IE or a general bug.

Screenshot:

[image: dots prepended to the label of the answer posting button]

Answer (score 3):

**FYI**

A workarround is to put a selectable anchor between the wmd-textarea and the button, with a tabindex set accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed, IE should switch to compatibility view automatically.

Error location: wmd.js?v=3297 character 22805
Error: text attribute cannot be set, unexpected method call or attribute access.