# "Post Your Answer" button is prefixed by bullet points at runtime

Tags: bug, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Tabbing breaks SO's ask question form in IE8](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/stackoverflow-ie8-issue-bug)

While posting answers (on Stack Overflow, at least), I've noticed that the "Ask Your Question" gets prefixed by a bullet point (●). In fact, I've seen it go up to three (though one at a time). I am using Internet Explorer 8 in normal mode (i.e., not "Compatibility View").

It's definitely not being rendered that way as I've seen it happen while entering text. Very strange.

Comment: This has been noticed and reproduced: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/stackoverflow-ie8-issue-bug

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't show up in the search!