# Pressing tab when writing a question makes IE8 freeze (to death)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editor

I am experiencing a bug where, when I'm writing an answer and accidently press the TAB key, IE freezes, and I need to kill it entirely. It is frustrating because I lose whatever I've written. Has anyone else experienced this?

**UPDATE**

I have now found a method to reproduce. The error does not occur in the exact same place every time, but it will crash the IE eventually.

Start writing an answer with the following content (not including the lines):

---

asd asd asd `asd asd asd` asd asd asd

```
asd asd asd
```

---

Now, press tab. The little "an error ocurred on the page" IE javascript icon will appear in the lower left corner.

Now mark everything in the textbox with the mouse, and delete it.

Start typing from scratch:

---

asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd

---

**Added this since @Rejoice reported inability to reproduce** 
Now press tab again, and (if you can, sometimes it already freezes before this) go back and keep typing.

At some point, and always when pressing space, the page will freeze completely.

Comment: Probably it's because your room is too cold. IE's melting point is quite high. :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the freeze, but I am getting the inability to press `tab` after completing the first step.

Comment: @Rejoice, I added more some extra info. Can you reproduce if you follow the steps now?

Comment: @Klaus nope, strange, I can't reproduce it at all now - even after restarting IE. Will try again next time I restart the machine.

Comment: Can't reproduce on WinXP SP3, IE8 (I've tried your steps, repeatedly, keeps working) - have you tried reproducing this with IE in "no plugins" mode? Some plugins for IE are subtly subversive in this regard.

Comment: @Piskvor, no I have not tried that. Will do. Btw, I'm using IE8 on Win7.

Comment: @Piskvor, I can reproduce the error in "no add-ons" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but I don't have the rep to edit the question, here are some details regarding the script error that **always** occurs when the tab key is pressed during answer editing.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Sat, 18 Dec 2010 15:09:14 UTC

Message: Could not set the text property. Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 1
Char: 26035
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/Js/wmd.js?v=438bf97578da

Here is my re-hydration of the function the above refers to from the wmd.js file:-

```
this.setInputAreaSelectionStartEnd= function ()
{
    if (p.selectionStart || p.selectionStart === 0)
    {
        q.start = p.selectionStart;
        q.end = p.selectionEnd
    }
    else
    {
        if (d.selection)
        {
            q.text = h.fixEolChars(p.value);
            var s;
            if (k.ieRetardedClick && k.ieCachedRange)
            {
                s = k.ieCachedRange;
                k.ieRetardedClick = false
            }       
            else
            {
                s = d.selection.createRange()
            }
            var r = h.fixEolChars(s.text);
            var u = "\x07";
            var v = u+r+u;

            s.text = v;  // Error happens here

            var w = h.fixEolChars(p.value);
            s.moveStart("character",-v.length);
            s.text = r;
            q.start = w.indexOf(u);
            q.end = w.lastIndexOf(u) - u.length;
            var t = q.text.length - h.fixEolChars(p.value).length;
           if (t)
           {
                s.moveStart("character", -r.length);
                while(t--)
                {
                    r += "\n";
                    q.end += 1
                }
                s.text = r
             }
             this.setInputAreaSelection()
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was composed in IE8. I am now pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Nothing bad happened, but the Post Your Answer button does have some [extraneous bullets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/stackoverflow-ie8-issue-bug) in it now..

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does not happen *every* single time. But I have experienced it before. I have a feeling that it happens when the answer includes indented code. I will try to investigate further and see if I can come up with the steps to reproduce.

Comment: I have updated the answer with steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Klaus: I'm experiencing this but __a lot__  pretty much 50:50 each time I've accidently pressed tab (which I also do a lot) IE8 will freeze. Even with draft saving you still stand to lose quite a lot of effort

Comment: See also my "answer" here.