# Cannot undo the first modification in the inline editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor

In the new, awesome inline editor, I can't undo the very first modification. Although I *can* undo subsequent modifications.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on `edit` to bring up the inline editor
2. Type/insert a letter
3. Press the undo button in the toolbar (or `Ctrl+Z`, the effect is the same).

The undo button becomes grayed out but the modification isn't undone. More generally, after making some modifications and pressing `Ctrl+Z` repeatedly, I go back to the state after applying the first modification, not to the post's original content.

Reproduced with Chrome 13.0.782.41 (Linux) and Firefox 3.5.19 (Debian).

Comment: Yup, same thing on Chrome (version whatever) in Windows 7. The *caret* moves as if the letter is erased, but the letter isn't actually erased. Nice find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a side effect of [this (pre-inline editing) bugfix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87844/when-creating-an-answer-accidental-tab-can-ruin-the-session/87863#87863). To fix that issue, we prevented recording the undo history if the input box was not the active element on the page.

This broke with the inline editing, because at the moment that the editor is initialized, the input area is not the focused element yet (only a few milliseconds later). Hence the initial contents of the input area weren't recorded, and thus the very first change couldn't be undone.

This is fixed in the next build.